# Composer install with separate docker container

Tags: docker-compose, composer-php

I would like to install composer container separately when docker setup. I found some similar answers.

- Most of them are installing composer inside a container `composer install` (Eg.  app container below code ). I think that is not cool!
- Some use `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash composer install`. That is manually working process.
- Some use volume mount the whole application. Yeah, that is easy and working. But,It is not ok in production environments.

**That's why I want to install composer container separately**

Below are some parts of my codes

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/production/7.4/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - ./docker/production/7.4/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini  
    networks: 
      - app-network
    depends_on: 
      - composer       

  composer:
    container_name: composer
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"    
    image: composer
    command: /bin/bash "/app/docker/production/7.4/start-composer.sh"
    volumes: 
      - ./:/app:rw
    networks: 
      - app-network
```

Here is start-composer.sh file

```
cd /app
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
composer dump-autoload
```

I think I don't need to show `/docker/production/7.4/Dockerfile` file  because I don't want to use `composer install` directly inside that container

when I run composer, it is installing outside directory, not in app container /var/www folder.

So, how should I make composer container to be able to install automatically.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Did you properly mount the expected folders?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase , Mounting solution is good when developing, Not on production

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, there's no need to use Composer on a production system